# How to find whether some text is highlighted and underlined on a webpage with Selenium(Java/Python)?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

How to find whether some text is highlighted and underlined on a webpage with Selenium(Java/Python)?

I came across above question in my recent interview. Could anyone answer if knows?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By Checking the Style Attribute (text-decoration) you can understand if that word is underlined or not. And for highlight you can check for particular css style or `"<mark> *** </mark>"` tag.

Comment: Thanks for answering Swaroop Humane!! Could you provide an example for what you explained above?